# Not able to integrate flask_mysqlb with swagger-codegen for python-flask

Tags: python-2.7, flask, swagger-codegen, flask-mysql

I was able to successfully generate python-flask server boiler-plate code by defining the API in Swagger 2.0.

In the generated code, multiple controllers have been created via which I intend to build connections to MySQL database to generate responses back.

I am facing issues while using flask_mysqldb library to do that. I have defined the mysql connection in the **main**.py which resides at the root and initializes the application.

```
mysql = MySQL()
mysql.init_app(app.app)
```

However, inside the controller, I am unable to use the mysql object to make connections to the database. If I define the above mentioned mysql object in one of the controller functions, I am able to fetch the data once, but it fails the next time and gives me a 500 error.

Please help me understand how can I pass the mysql object from main flask application to the controllers or other custom functions that I define.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: I was able to get the code working! :)

Comment: I basically had to setup Flask 'Application Context Stack' with the MySqlDb connection. Then I used that MySqlDb connection from the stack in all my functions/controllers.